# Destructor called without copy or move constructor during array initialization on MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have tried this on MSVC versions 19.10.25019.0 and 19.11.25547.0 in debug and release builds and get the same result.

---

The following program prints `0       1       2       3       4       5`. 
I expected either

- no output, or
- a combination of move or copy constructor calls with the destructor calls.

Instead, it seems the destructor was called for 6 of the 7 elements and no copy or move constructor calls were made.

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyChar {
    MyChar(char c) : c{c}{}
    MyChar() = default;

    MyChar(const MyChar&) { std::cout << "copy"; };
    MyChar& operator=(const MyChar&) { std::cout << "assign"; return *this; };
    MyChar(MyChar&&) { std::cout << "move"; };
    MyChar& operator=(const MyChar&&) { std::cout << "move assign"; return *this; };

    ~MyChar() { std::cout << cnt++ << '\t'; }

    char c{'H'};
    static int cnt;
};

int MyChar::cnt{};

int main()
{
    auto arr1 = new MyChar[7]{'D'};
}
```

Why is the destructor being called 6 times without delete (or without the compiler initializing via a copy or a move)?

Comment: Did you miss `delete [] arr1;` in your snippet? Otherwise there should not be a destructor called: https://ideone.com/x0ACU9 vs https://ideone.com/6S6fO7

Comment: Your assignment operators are broken. Not that it should matter here, but...

Comment: @mch I left out the delete on purpose. Please see the online MSVC example [here](http://rextester.com/IYSY57638).

Comment: @rex 1) Broken in the sense of undefined behavior, which is invoked if you don't return anything from non-`void` function. 2) Why did you expect your `MyChar` instances to be copied/moved?

Comment: @rex Wait, I am confused. You list "_a combination of move or copy constructor calls with the destructor calls._" as one of the expected outputs, but you don't expect them to be copied or moved? Which is it?

Comment: @rex Where did I ask about you expecting them to happen in isolation? Please read the comment again.

Comment: Originally I thought your question was why no copy/move was being done, and I tried to answer that: because you're not doing any copying/moving as you (apparently) expected to be. If your real question is just: "why is the dtor being invoked when I didn't use `delete`?", the answer is simpler: because of a buggy compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In playing around with this in the VC compiler, and inspecting the generated assembly code, this appears to be a compiler bug related to the `MyChar() = default` constructor.  Replacing it with `MyChar() { }` gets rid of the unexpected destructor calls.

By adding some additional code into the destructor, the objects being destroyed are the default-initialized members of `arr1`.  Adding in a call to `delete [] arr1`, along with including the address of the object being destroyed in the destructor, shows that the first element is destroyed once, while the other 6 are destroyed twice - once when `arr1` is constructed, and again when the delete call is made.

This should be reported to Microsoft.  It occurs in both VC2015 and VC2017.